# Dataproc hive operator not running hql file stored in storage bucket

Tags: python, hive, google-cloud-dataproc, airflow

I am trying to run hql file present in cloud storage using airflow script,there are two parameters through which we can pass the path to DataprocHiveOperator :

1. Query: 'gs://bucketpath/filename.q'

`Error occuring - cannot recognize input near 'gs' ':' '/'`

2. query_uri :'gs://bucketpath/filename.q'

`Error occuring: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to DataProcHiveOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'query_uri': 'gs://poonamp_pcloud/hive_file1.q'`

Using Query param , i have successfully run hive queries(`select * from table`)

**Is there any way to run hql file stored in cloud storage bucket through dataprochiveoperator ?**

Comment: I'm try run a hive query on dataproc using composer. Where should we be storing the data for this? Is it on Bucket or dataproc itself.

Comment: Hey @JohnConstantine you can do this in two ways. 1) You can directly give query command on dataproc itself by selecting query, otherwise you need to select query file instead and need to store your query file inside google storage bucket and then you need to give that location. an example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438293/8660480)

Comment: @aditi please mark answer as correct if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are using both **`query`** as well as **`query_uri`**.

If you are **querying using a file**, you have to use **`query_uri`** and **`query = None`** OR you can ignore writing query.

If you are using **`inline query`** then you have to use **`query`**.

Here is a sample for **querying through a file**.

```
HiveInsertingTable = DataProcHiveOperator(task_id='HiveInsertingTable',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default', 
    queri_ury="gs://us-central1-bucket/data/sample_hql.sql",
    cluster_name='cluster-name',
    region='us-central1',
    dag=dag)
```

Answer (score 1):

`query_uri` is the indeed the correct parameter for running an hql file off of Cloud Storage. However, it was only added to the `DataProcHiveOperator` in https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/pull/2402. Based on the warning message you got, I don't think you're running on code that supports the parameter. The change is not on the latest release (1.8.2), so you'll need to wait for another release or grab it off the master branch.