# Unable to query using file in Data Proc Hive Operator

Tags: hive, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I am unable to query with .sql file in `DataProcHiveOperator`.
Though the documentation tells that we can query using file. Link of the documentation [Here](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#airflow.contrib.operators.dataproc_operator.DataProcHiveOperator)

It is working fine when I give query directly
Here is my sample code which is working fine with writing query directly:

```
HiveInsertingTable = DataProcHiveOperator(task_id='HiveInsertingTable',
gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default', 
query='CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(NAME STRING);',
cluster_name='cluster-name',
region='us-central1',
dag=dag)
```

Querying with file :

```
HiveInsertingTable = DataProcHiveOperator(task_id='HiveInsertingTable',
gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default', 
query='gs://us-central1-bucket/data/sample_hql.sql',
query_uri="gs://us-central1-bucket/data/sample_hql.sql
cluster_name='cluster-name',
region='us-central1',
dag=dag)
```

There is no error on sample_hql.sql script. 
It is reading file location as a query and throwing me the error as:

```
Query: 'gs://bucketpath/filename.q'
Error occuring - cannot recognize input near 'gs' ':' '/'
```

Similar issue has also been raised [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46315305/dataproc-hive-operator-not-running-hql-file-stored-in-storage-bucket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you have passed `query='gs://us-central1-bucket/data/sample_hql.sql'` as well.

You should pass exactly 1 of `query` or `queri_uri`.

The code in your question has both of them, so remove `query` or use the following code:

```py
HiveInsertingTable = DataProcHiveOperator(task_id='HiveInsertingTable',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default', 
    query_uri="gs://us-central1-bucket/data/sample_hql.sql",
    cluster_name='cluster-name',
    region='us-central1',
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: Yes that's correct. And also the spelling of "query_uri" was written as "queri_uri". My bad.
Thanks @kaxil