# Running Hive queries with GCP Composer

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

So I plan on using GCP Composer to run a couple of Hive jobs.

Is using Hive along with Dataproc the best way to do this?

Where should the data be stored for this? Can Dataproc read data from Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways you can submit your hive jobs in dataproc.
**YES** dataproc reads data from google bucket. I have already answered this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438293/8660480)

There are few wasy you can submit your hive jobs in dataporc.
 1) You can directly give command by selecting query option.
 2) You can select query-file option and then mention the location of the file (Google storage). Example for that is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53438293/8660480)

Now coming to your first question, **Is using hive along with Dataproc the best way to do this?**   -
 That's entirely depends on your requirement. There are many job options available, you got to choose based on your requirement and hence that becomes the best. I could have answered it more clearly if you could have specified more details about your requirement.
 Well I can give you a gist of **HIVE JOBS**, so that your an sort out your requirement.

You can do the following thing in Hive jobs :

- You can give inline query (one or more)
- You can give query command form query file (one or more)
- You can add jar files in your hive - that can be for any purpose such as UDF (one or more)
- You can add additional properties to configure your job
- You can automate the job

  That's all about basic hive jobs.

Airflow [Data Proc Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#dataproc-operators) has all the available operators which you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Dataproc can read data from GCS Bucket. For example read this: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc#creating_a_hive_table

And then you can use `DataProcHiveOperator` to run queries on it using Cloud Composer.